# Trying to keep track of number of outstanding AJAX requests in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey, sandbox

I am using Selenium to test a web application and am not allowed to modify the application's javascript code.  I am trying to track the number of outstanding AJAX requests by using GreaseMonkey to override XMLHttpRequest.send.  The new send() will basically wrap what was set as the onreadystatechange callback, check the readyState, incrementing or decrementing the counter as appropriate, and calling the original callback function.

The problem that I'm having appears to be a privilege issue because if I just browse to a page in a normal firefox browser, open firebug and paste in the following code, it seems to work fine:

```
document.ajax_outstanding = 0;
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend != 'function') {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        console.log('in new send');
        console.log('this.onreadystatechange = ' + this.onreadystatechange);
        this.oldonreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 2) {
                /* LOADED */
                document.ajax_outstanding++;
                console.log('set ajax_outstanding to ' + document.ajax_outstanding);
            }
            this.oldonreadystatechange.handleEvent.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                /* COMPLETED */
                document.ajax_outstanding--;
                console.log('set ajax_outstanding to ' + document.ajax_outstanding);
            }
        };
        this.oldsend.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Now if I use a slightly modified version of that snippet from within a GreaseMonkey user script like so:

```
unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding = 0;
if (typeof unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend != 'function') {
    unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        GM_log('in new send');
        GM_log('this.onreadystatechange = ' + this.onreadystatechange);
        this.oldonreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
        this.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 2) {
                /* LOADED */
                unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding++;
                GM_log('set ajax_outstanding to ' + unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding);
            }
            this.oldonreadystatechange.handleEvent.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                /* COMPLETED */
                unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding--;
                GM_log('set ajax_outstanding to ' + unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding);
            }
        };
        this.oldsend.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

and I go to a page, do something that causes an AJAX request, I get the following message in the javascript error console:

```
http://www.blah.com/gmscripts/overrides: in new send
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal value" nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///tmp/customProfileDir41e7266f56734c97a2ca02b1f7f528e1/extensions/%7Be4a8a97b-f2ed-450b-b12d-ee082ba24781%7D/components/greasemonkey.js :: anonymous :: line 372" data: no]
```

So it appears to be throwing the exception when trying to access this.onreadystatechange

Presumably, this is due to the sandboxed environment.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am not tied to this solution, so any other suggestions for doing what I need are welcome.  It's just that I've tried several others and this seems to be the most promising.  The requirement is that I need to make sure that the counter gets to 0 *after* the readyState goes to 4 and the onreadystatechange callback has finished execution.

Answer (score 3):

I've made something myself: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/skp28agx/ (updated 22 Jan 2015)

The script (should run before anything else):

```
(function(xhr) {
    xhr.active = 0;
    var pt = xhr.prototype;
    var _send = pt.send;
    pt.send = function() {
        xhr.active++;
        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
            if ( this.readyState == 4 ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    xhr.active--;
                }, 1);
            }
        });
        _send.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(XMLHttpRequest);
```

And the jsFiddle's test script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('button'),
        active = btn.querySelector('span');

    btn.onclick = function() {
        // jQuery for easy ajax. `delay` is a jsFiddle argument
        // to keep some requests active longer.
        jQuery.post('/echo/json/', {
            delay: Math.random() * 3,
        });
    };

    updateActive();

    function updateActive() {
        active.textContent = XMLHttpRequest.active;
        requestAnimationFrame(updateActive);
    }
};
```

It updates the counter in the button every animation frame (~ 60 times per second), separate from the AJAX requests. Whatever you do, however fast and much you click it, the counter should always end up at 0 after a few seconds.

Comment: did you really give a localhost address or is it my eyes? =))

Comment: Note that this modification to `XMLHttpRequest.send` needs to be installed before any AJAX requests are sent, or the counter could be wrong.  Also, I think it might be better to decrement `active` after calling `this._onreadystatechange` (if you consider a request to be active until its event handler finishes).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following:

```
unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding = 0;
if (typeof unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend != 'function') {
    unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend = unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
        unsafeWindow.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldsend.apply(this, arguments);
        this.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if (this.readyState == 2) {
                /* LOADED */
                unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding++;
                console.log('set ajax_outstanding to ' + unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding);
            } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                /* COMPLETED */
                unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding--;
                console.log('set ajax_outstanding to ' + unsafeWindow.document.ajax_outstanding);
            }
        }, false);
    };
}
```