# Overriding XMLHttpRequest's send method

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to log (and later modify) the data `XMLHttpRequest` sends to a server by overriding `XMLHttpRequest.send` function.

My function logs the data correctly to the console, however the request doesn't finish, therefore the browser keeps waiting for the response indefinitely.

Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

```js
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
var newSend = function(vData) { console.log("data: " + vData); realSend(vData); };
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410218/trying-to-keep-track-of-number-of-outstanding-ajax-requests-in-firefox

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
// here "this" points to the XMLHttpRequest Object.
var newSend = function(vData) { console.log("data: " + vData); this.realSend(vData); };
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
```

Answer (score 24):

You have forgot `this`:

```
this.realSend(vData);
```

However, you don't need to add a new method to the prototype:

```
var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
    send.call(this, data);
}
```

Using closure, you can also avoid rogue variables:

```
!function(send){
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (data) {
        send.call(this, data);
    }
}(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send);
```

Comment: Thank you for the closure suggestion, the code does seem a lot cleaner that way.

Comment: [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3755606/238421)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data to change is a JSON string you can write an interceptor like this one:

```js
// Closure to contain variables and ! to avoid possible concatenation issues with other codes.
!function(){
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype._original_send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
  let interceptor_send = function(data){
    try {
      // Adding data to the JSON string, 
      // translating in JSON object to validate it's content and add an attribute.
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      obj._custom_added_data = 'Your data';
      let new_data = JSON.stringify(obj);
      this._original_send(new_data);
    }
    catch(err) {
      // In case the payload was not a JSON string,
      // do not add anything and send the original payload.
      this._original_send(data);
    }

};
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = interceptor_send;
}();
```