# How to intercept a GET ajax request from javascript in iOS wkWebView (using objective-c)

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have a hybrid app that runs on *iOS*, and uses *wkWebView* (the language is *objective c*).
**I am trying to intercept a GET request from the javascript side, in the iOS wkWebView side.**
In *javascript*, I make a *fetch*, or *xhr* request call, but it is not intercepted in *wkWebView*.
(An equivalent version of the app that runs on *Android*, and uses *webView* works ok - the *fetch* request, is intercepted in *webView* via *shouldInterceptRequest*.)

If I do a window.location.href call, the call is intercepted (in decidePolicyForNavigationAction) (but this is not a request).
But if I do *fetch* or *xhr* ([XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr)) request, the call is **NOT intercepted**.

Several questions on the Internet like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133512/intercept-request-with-wkwebview%C2%A0) ask about how to intercept POST requests.
My case is even more basic. I cannot intercept a GET request

My code looks like this:

Javascript code:

```
let url = 'http://example.com';

// try3 - using href - call is intercepted in iOS (but this is not a request...)
window.location.href = url;

# --------------------------------------------------------------

// try2 - using xhr - call is NOT intercepted in iOS
function makeRequest (method, url, done) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        done(null, xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        done(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

makeRequest('GET', url, function (err, datums) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log(datums);
});

# --------------------------------------------------------------

// try1 - using fetch - call is NOT intercepted in iOS
response = await fetch(url);
```

native Objective-C code:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
  
    DTLogDebug (@"BEG decidePolicyForNavigationAction");
    ...
```

**How can iOS intercept xhr ajax requests?**

Thanks