# I there a Flutter package that implements UIWebView?

Tags: ios, flutter, uiwebview

I need to use iOS UIWebView in my Flutter application.
I there a Flutter package which implements UIWebView?
There are a lot of packages implementing WKWebView, but I did not find UIWebView for Flutter.

PS
I need to intercept http requests from WebView. It is possible to do it with WKWebView, but this solution has a lot of [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67228256/8705119). That is why I want to use UIWebView.

Comment: You can no longer submit apps to the App Store that use UIWebView.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, really (source: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b). Thanks.