# WKWebView Localization iOS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am loading a `URL` in `WKWebview` in which I am passing "`Accept-Language`" header for displaying page as per passed language.

```
  var aRequest = URLRequest.init(url: MyUrl)
  aRequest.setValue("fr-CA", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
  self.webView.load(aRequest)
```

The above works properly in case of one of the URL and doesn't work in case of other. How to correctly use the header of Accept-Language?

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by [How to set custom HTTP headers to requests made by a WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868935/how-to-set-custom-http-headers-to-requests-made-by-a-wkwebview) and played around a bit with it.
This is what I ended up with:

Set the navigationDelegate of the webView to self and implement

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    guard navigationAction.request.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language") != "fr-CA" && navigationAction.navigationType != .other else {
        decisionHandler(.allow)
        return
    }
    
    decisionHandler(.cancel)
    
    var request = navigationAction.request
    request.setValue("fr-CA", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Language")
    webView.load(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The locales which worked for me are as below:

```
  "fr-CA" - French
  "es" - Spanish
  "zh-CN" - Chinese
```