# How to retrieve http header values from a WKWebView

Tags: json, swift3, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` that enables users to login.  If they are successful I want to retrieve a userID, portalID and other information.  If the WebView downloads a JSON file with this information, how would I go about accessing it.  I know I can access http header information through the `WKNavigationDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I've learned that it is not possible to access custom http header information from `WKWebView`  As explained in this post:

> AFAIK sadly you cannot do this with WKWebView.
>
> It most certainly does not work in
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler: because the
>   navigationAction.request is read-only and a non-mutable NSURLRequest
>   instance that you cannot change.

[Discussion on WKWebView limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984212/how-to-add-httpheader-in-request-globally-for-ios-swift/37474812#37474812)