# How to retrieve html hidden value from WKWebView response?

Tags: ios, swift3, wkwebview

I am using a WKWebView to present a login page to the user.  After logging in, I would like to retrieve the users ID.  Initially wanted to include this in the Response Header, but apparently this is not possbile:
AFAIK sadly you cannot do this with WKWebView.

*It most certainly does not work in webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler: because the navigationAction.request is read-only and a non-mutable NSURLRequest instance that you cannot change.*

[How To add HttpHeader in request globally for ios swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984212/how-to-add-httpheader-in-request-globally-for-ios-swift/37474812#37474812)

As an alternative approach, I will attempt to add a hidden html field to the Response body:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="The retrieved userID">
```

How do I extract this value?

Comment: You should rather use Javascript bridge. When user logs in, Javascript executes a function in native code. Take a look at this article: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html

Comment: @mag_zbc I'm really looking for a simple solution.  I think I'll drop WKWebView and just use UIWebView.  I'll add the user ID to the response header.  For now, it will do.  Thanks.