# Adding Javascript to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Hi I know this seems like a super simple question, but I want to add this JS to my WebView:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=default&#038;ver=1.3.8'></script>
```

Now obviously I know this is HTML, but I am not sure what to put into 'evaluateJavaScript' in order to use the JS source. Sorry if this isn't very clear - I'm new to both Swift and JS. Thanks!

My swift code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=default&#038;ver=1.3.8'></script>") { (nil, error) in
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post what have you tried in Swift?

Comment: @AhmadF edited accordingly

Comment: Its too late - but you are using "evaluateJavascript" so you don't need explicit "<script></script>" - it will work without it

Answer (score 18):

Use built-in API `WKUserScript` inject JS:

```
let script =    """
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=default&#038;ver=1.3.8';
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                """
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)

let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.addUserScript(userScript)

let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewConfiguration.userContentController = contentController

let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
```

> forMainFrameOnly: A Boolean value indicating whether the script should be injected only into the main frame or into all frames(including iframe).

Comment: This answer works well, however would I be able to do this with a WKWebview created using IB? Thank you for your help

Comment: @RahulBasi It is not possible to set the configuration of the WKWebView through the outlet of WKWebView form the storyboard because the configuration property of the WKWebView is read only. However, if you really want to create WKWebView through xib or storyboard, you have to make a subclass of WKWebView, then instead of calling super initWithCoder, you'll need to use a different init method, such as initWithFrame:configuration:.

Comment: running your code without any changes gives me error like
"libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform"

Comment: While the configuration property is read only, the attached `WKWebViewConfiguration` is mutable. Example: `[self.webView.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:userScript];`