# Use Session Based Cookies in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, session, cookies, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to sign in using basic auth. There is a java session identifier (jsessionid) assigned and stored in a cookie. How can I store that cookie and use it when loading a WKWebView (or SafariViewController although I don't think that's possible, but I'd love to be wrong).

Comment: I did this but i was usign UIWebView, could it help?

Comment: It could help if I see what you did.

Comment: Using UIWebView, the ViewControlled implements UIWebViewDelegate, then sets the cookie in webView( ... shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest ... ).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add HTTP headers in request globally for iOS in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984212/how-to-add-http-headers-in-request-globally-for-ios-in-swift)