# How to support authorization token in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, webview, oauth-2.0, wkwebview

I have native iOS app and one of the flows of the app should be done with WebView. From native part of the app, user can navigate to WebView part. And, somehow, web page should identify user. I have authorization token stored in the app and of course I can pass that token in the headers of the WKWebView. And other stuff will be handle in the web (routing and etc). But is it a good and secure way of doing this? How can I easily integrate WebView in the app caring about token?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options here:

1. Using headers seems problematic according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984212/how-to-add-http-headers-in-request-globally-for-ios-in-swift) but hopefully you can get it to work. It feels like this will have reliability problems if the token ever expires in the web view, so you'll need to manage that.
2. Simple option: open a system browser - either Safari or a Safari View Controller. The user may have to sign in again though, which your stakeholders may not like.
3. More complex option: use the Javascript API to pass the token from the mobile UI to the web UI. This will give you full control, and the web app can call back the mobile app to refresh its token. It can be the best usability option if used sparingly. It requires tricky foundational work in both the web and mobile UIs though.

**SECURITY**

Passing the token from the Mobile UI to the Web UI is natural if both are part of the same logical application and access the same level of data. In this case option 1 or 3 would work.

If the apps have very different security levels (eg the web app is now getting a much higher privilege token than it usually gets), then I would not pass the token and would use option 2 instead.

**FURTHER DETAILS**

I wrote a quite detailed blog post on considerations a while back, and there is also a code sample you can run:

- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2020/06/17/mobile-web-integration-goals/)
- [Mobile Bridge Code in Web UI](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/mobile/mobileMethodCaller.ts)
- [Javascript Bridge Code in Mobile UI](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobileweb.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/Interop/JavascriptBridge.swift)

Comment: the links are not working anymore :(